# Geocoder Gem Reverse Geocoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reverse-geocoding, rails-geocoder

After watching [RailsCasts #273](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder) I want to use the [Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) gem. I've seen this:

```
class Skatepark < ActiveRecord::Base
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
  after_validation :fetch_address
  ...
end
```

which will reverse geocode the coordinates and populate `:address` with formatted_address.

Can I get this separated as `:street`, `:locality`, `:region`, `:country`, and `:postal_code` from the geocoder gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know your model but this is how you populate it. It's also documented in the page you referred to.

```
class Skatepark < ActiveRecord::Base
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude do |obj, results|
    if geo = results.first
      # populate your model
      obj.city    = geo.city
      obj.zipcode = geo.postal_code
      obj.country = geo.country_code
    end
  end
  after_validation :fetch_address
  ...
end
```

Comment: Don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks for the help!